# How to POST products, customers etc. to WordPress WooCommerce plugin via Delphi

Tags: json, wordpress, delphi, post, woocommerce

I have to write client on Delphi, that should add products, customers etc. to WP WooCommerce. If I do GET-request I get some data from my WP. I have to send that json.
Here is my GET-request returns [json string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHKbi.jpg)

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, System.JSON, IPPeerClient, System.Rtti,
  System.Bindings.Outputs, Vcl.Bind.Editors, Data.Bind.EngExt,
  Vcl.Bind.DBEngExt, Vcl.StdCtrls, Data.Bind.Components, REST.Client,
  Data.Bind.ObjectScope, REST.Authenticator.OAuth, REST.Authenticator.Basic,
  REST.Authenticator.Simple, REST.Types, REST.JSON, IdHMACSHA1, EncdDecd, HTTPApp,
  IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    RESTClient1: TRESTClient;
    RESTRequest1: TRESTRequest;
    RESTResponse1: TRESTResponse;
    HTTPBasicAuthenticator1: THTTPBasicAuthenticator;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
    Memo3: TMemo;
    Button4: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  jValue: TJSONValue;
begin

  HTTPBasicAuthenticator1.Username :=
    'ck_6f28f594097d674abf96ebb6b6856ab18b9*****';
  HTTPBasicAuthenticator1.Password :=
    'cs_1eede52f328af091dca5d6c7e0b6a0abc55*****';

  RESTClient1.Params.Clear;

  RESTClient1.AddParameter('consumer_key', HTTPBasicAuthenticator1.Username, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
  RESTClient1.AddParameter('consumer_secret', HTTPBasicAuthenticator1.Password, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
  RESTRequest1.Resource := 'products';
  RESTRequest1.Execute;
  jValue := RESTResponse1.JSONValue;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(jValue.ToString);
end;
```

Can someone explain or show how and in which datatype I should send my POST-request for example to feel my products title, id and price? 
[here is documentation of WooCommerce if it helps](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#create-a-customer)
Thank you ))

So I solved my problem))

I try to send `{"customers":[{"email":"example@mail....` as in my get-request or `{"email":"example@mail....` as in documentation of WooCommerce. I try to send it without array too `{"customers":{"email":"example@mail....`.

All the time I got my error `{"code":"json_missing_callback_param","message":"Missing parameter data"}`

But all that you need is just to send "customer" not "customers" as object and all parameters from documentation (email, first_name ....)

So here is my code that work and I can POST now:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
   Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
   System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
   Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, System.JSON, IPPeerClient, System.Rtti,
   System.Bindings.Outputs, Vcl.Bind.Editors, Data.Bind.EngExt,
   Vcl.Bind.DBEngExt, Vcl.StdCtrls, Data.Bind.Components, REST.Client,
   Data.Bind.ObjectScope, REST.Authenticator.OAuth, REST.Authenticator.Basic,
   REST.Authenticator.Simple, REST.Types, REST.JSON, IdHMACSHA1, EncdDecd, HTTPApp,
   IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  Button1: TButton;
  Memo1: TMemo;
  RESTClient1: TRESTClient;
  RESTRequest1: TRESTRequest;
  RESTResponse1: TRESTResponse;
  HTTPBasicAuthenticator1: THTTPBasicAuthenticator;
  Button2: TButton;
  Button3: TButton;
  Memo2: TMemo;
  Edit1: TEdit;
  IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
  Memo3: TMemo;
  Button4: TButton;
  procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
  procedure Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
private
  { Private-Deklarationen }
public
  { Public-Deklarationen }
end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

  implementation

  {$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  jValue: TJSONValue;
begin

  HTTPBasicAuthenticator1.Username :=
'ck_6f28f594097d674abf96ebb6b6856ab18b9*****';
  HTTPBasicAuthenticator1.Password :=
'cs_1eede52f328af091dca5d6c7e0b6a0abc55*****';

  RESTClient1.Params.Clear;

  RESTRequest1.Resource := 'customers';
  RESTRequest1.ResourceSuffix :=
'?consumer_key={consumer_key}&consumer_secret={consumer_secret}';
  RESTRequest1.AddParameter('consumer_key', HTTPBasicAuthenticator1.Username,
TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkURLSEGMENT);
  RESTRequest1.AddParameter('consumer_secret', HTTPBasicAuthenticator1.Password,
TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkURLSEGMENT);
  RESTRequest1.AddBody(a.ToJSON, ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
  RESTRequest1.Execute;
  jValue := RESTResponse1.JSONValue;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(jValue.ToString);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some coders report problem with oAuth1, cause:

**The OAuth parameters must be added as query string parameters and not included in the Authorization header. This is because there is no reliable cross-platform way to get the raw request headers in WordPress.**

Solution:

```
procedure Tfrm_Main.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    s: String;
begin

    RESTRequest.ResetToDefaults;
    RESTClient.ResetToDefaults;
    RESTResponse.ResetToDefaults;
    RESTResponseDataSetAdapter.ResetToDefaults;
    OAuth1_FitBit.ResetToDefaults;

    OAuth1_FitBit.ConsumerKey := edt_FitBit_ConsumerKey.Text;
    OAuth1_FitBit.ConsumerSecret := edt_FitBit_ConsumerSecret.Text;

    RESTClient.BaseURL := edt_FitBit_BaseURL.Text;  

    RESTRequest.Resource := edt_FitBit_ResourceURI.Text;

    RESTRequest.AddParameter('oauth_consumer_key', edt_FitBit_ConsumerKey.Text);
    RESTRequest.AddParameter('oauth_signature_method', 'HMAC-SHA1');
    RESTRequest.AddParameter('oauth_nonce', OAuth1_FitBit.nonce);
    RESTRequest.AddParameter('oauth_timestamp',
    OAuth1_FitBit.timeStamp.DeQuotedString);
    RESTRequest.AddParameter('oauth_version', '1.0');
    s := OAuth1_FitBit.SigningClass.BuildSignature(RESTRequest, OAuth1_FitBit);
    RESTRequest.AddParameter('oauth_signature', s);

    RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmGET;

    RESTRequest.Execute;
end;
```

Comment: Provide an explanation to accompany your answer to make it clear.